# Swift Println and preserving quotation marks after array sort

Tags: swift

I have a big nested arrays with 250 arrays in this form:

```
[["europe", "eastern europe", "belarus", "frequent"],
    ["europe", "eastern europe", "bulgaria", "frequent"],
    ["europe", "eastern europe", "czech republic", "frequent"],
    ["europe", "eastern europe", "hungary", "frequent"],
    ["europe", "eastern europe", "moldova", "not"],
    ["europe", "eastern europe", "romania", "frequent"],
    ["europe", "eastern europe", "slovakia", "frequent"]]
```

This is only a sample the original one is not sorted alphabetically and much bigger.
I need to sort this array alphabetically, and hard code in my file the sorted array. I was thinking of using the sort function, then println the array and copy it into my code:

```
 var myArray = ListOfCountries().countries
    myArray.sort({ $0[2] < $1[2] })
    println(myArray)
```

That does sort it correctly, but println looks like this:

```
[[asia, southern central asia, afghanistan, frequent], 
[europe, southern europe, albania, frequent], 
[oceania, polynesia, american samoa, not], 
[europe, southern europe, andorra, not], 
[africa, central africa, angola, frequent],
 [americas, caribbean, anguilla, not]]
```

I've lost the quotation mark thus I can't copy past it on my code and elsewhere where I need to with the "".
How could I do the same thing but get access to sorted arrays with the quotation marks ?

Comment: That's because they're strings. If you want parentheses, use escaped ones: `"\"asia\""`.

Comment: Were the quotation marks there in the first place? I'd say the only appear in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention *preserve quotes* in your question. That makes me think that you think the quotes are part of your strings and that the sorting removed them.

But this is not the case. If you use a string like `"europe"` in Swift *code,* the representation in *memory* is simply `europe` without the quotes.

What `println()` writes to the Console is an *external representation* of objects. In case of `String` values, it prints them without adding quotes. This is just an implementation detail and has nothing to do with how strings are stored in your application.

You mention that you later need this array with the strings quoted. If that means that you need this data in `JSON` format then you will need to use a JSON encoder, which will take your array of strings and write it out according to JSON formatting rules, which *do* include the quotes.

Comment: that was it: jsonification of the array then I can println in json format, with the quotes. Tis

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
debugPrintln(myArray)
```

It quotes strings with `"`.

```
/// Write to the console the textual representation of `x` most suitable
/// for debugging, followed by a newline.
///
/// ... snip ...
///
/// See also: `debugPrint(x)`
func debugPrintln<T>(x: T)
```